# renaming hdpim.db on my macbook Pro to update PS

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop

Trying to update Adobe PS but get the error message 105. I have tried renaming hdpim.db to old_hdpim.db.  any ideas please.

Comment: Adobe has a pretty slick escalation for this. https://helpx.adobe.com/download-install/kb/unable-to-install-error-105.html